# How can I add EC2 nodes and have them start picking up from a pool of shared work?

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, distributed-computing

I'm new to AWS, but it's the stack we use, so this needs to work on AWS.

I don't see anything in the AWS toolset that helps me spin up another EC2 node and then automatically handle the allocation of a bunch of tasks to the new node.

So, as an example, I might have a bunch of requests to create Fibonacci numbers. Initially, a single JVM on a single EC2 node could fire up, steal a batch of numbers to process, and process them.

As load increases, a second node could fire up, and its JVM steal the next batch of numbers to process.

Note: no single number must be processed more than once, ideally. The odd dupe doesn't matter, but we need to avoid conflicting on entire batches of work to be done.

I could store the tasks in RDS, or maybe in DynamoDB. I'd then have to mark entries as reserved by a particular EC2 node for processing, and clear them down once completed. Worse, I'd have to have some kind of recovery logic for if an EC2 node has gone down and left some entries marked for processing.

I could use something non-AWS-y, like Redis, and distribute data in memory over the JVMs. I still need to persist the entries at some point, as they need to be durable, but this would presumably be more performant.

I guess I'm thinking this must be a really common requirement: to have shared state and process it over a changing number of nodes, that there must be a solution out there already.

Comment: See: https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/autoscaling/

Comment: I don't see anything that addresses shared state, or allocation of work from a pool.

Comment: Assuming all the nodes in your ASG are configured with the same AMI, you can create an autoscaling rule based on CPU usage or other metrics available on couldwatch, this way when your ASG is overloaded  AWS will automatically spin up new instances. If you don't have your instance logic baked into an AMI, meaning, if any new instance that you're adding requires manual installation and configuration - then AFAIK it's not possible to auto-scale without manual intervention.

Comment: This isn't about scaling AWS instances, but of the application running on those instances. When a new instance starts, the application running on it needs to reserve a a bunch of work to do. When it dies, other application nodes need to realise that work is now free to do.

Comment: You are running your own logic, AWS services don't have context/insight into your logic - these are things you need to implement by yourself. That said, there are open-source projects that do exactly what you want. Check out [Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

The tasks to be completed should be published to an SQS queue. The application that does the work on each instance will then consume from the queue. If you launch a new EC2 instance it will start consuming from the queue. Once a task has been successfully completed the application can delete it from the queue. If the task does not complete successfully (the instance gets terminated or the application dies unexpectedly) the task will remain on the queue for the next consuming application.

Note that SQS guarantees messages will be delivered "at least once" (https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/) so your application should be able to handle duplicate tasks appropriately.

Additionally, you can set autoscaling policies on the size of the SQS queue in order to consume all of the tasks at peak load times.

Comment: That's interesting - that would probably work for the Fibonacci example. I have an additional complication though:the work is time based - i.e. at time 1, do set of tasks A, then at time 2, do set of tasks B. In fact, the tasks in my case are to send messages to a message queue... but only at intervals set by  the caller. Bit like an alarm clock.

Comment: If you have two sets of tasks (A and B) you could use two SQS queues. Then your applications could consume from the respective queue during the set time period. (You could use a third SQS queue for the message destination queue.)